# How to connect mysql database using vba?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, database

Option Explicit

Sub excelmysql()
' Connection variables
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
    ' Table action variables
Dim i As Long    ' counter
Dim strSQL As String    ' SQL to perform various actions
Dim table1 As String
Dim field1 As String, field2 As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim vtype As Variant

Server_Name = "localhost"    ' Enter your server name here - if running from a local computer use 127.0.0.1

Database_Name = "PRMJIRA"    ' Enter your database name here

User_ID = "root"    ' enter your user ID here

Password = "Pradee@1234"    ' Enter your password here

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" _
          & ";SERVER=" & Server_Name _
          & ";DATABASE=" & Database_Name _
          & ";UID=" & User_ID _
          & ";PWD=" & Password _
          & ";OPTION=16427"

'conn.Open


vtype = Array("varchar(255)", "Text", "LongText", "Int(10)", "Float", "Double", "Date", "Time")    ' array of commonly used MySQL variable types
table1 = "P" & Range("H1").Value

field1 = "field1text"

field2 = "field2text"

strSQL = "CREATE TABLE `" & table1 & "` (`" _
         & field1 & "` " & vtype(0) & ",`" _
         & field2 & "` " & vtype(4) _
         & ")"

conn.Execute strSQL

On Error Resume Next

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What kind of error did you encounter?

Comment: I am unable to connect to odbc driver its giving me automation error

Comment: Which line it is then?

Comment: conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" _
          & ";SERVER=" & Server_Name _
          & ";DATABASE=" & Database_Name _
          & ";UID=" & User_ID _
          & ";PWD=" & Password _
          & ";OPTION=16427"

conn.Open

Comment: It stops when I hit on conn.open line

Comment: @user3500441, just tested with identical connection string, works fine. Please check your server, db, uid and pass. Include on error goto and Debug.Print Err.Description lines, you will know the reason.